# Best way to compare program-generated data with data stored in DB?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, .net-3.5

I am writing a C# application to scrape data from a website and then use it to update database tables.

The data I scrape relates to, say 10 rows in the database. We only want to insert the data if the data has actually changed. I have written the SQL procs to make the changes, but I am not sure how to implement the first stage- checking whether the program-generated data (scraped from website) is different to the already-stored data in SQL Server.

My current approach was to use the class in my program which represents the data, populate a dictionary of instances of these objects (in this case there would be 10 key-value pairs), populate with the website data and then to grab the SQL table data, iterate all 10 rows, use my class again to create another 10 objects and then compare the two sets of dictionary objects using a function I wrote in the data class called getHash(), eg:

Does `websitedict.get(key1).getHash() == dbdict.get(key1).getHash()`?

etc

Comment: Please give us the schema, and ideally some example (even if it's fictional) data. Do you intend to update existing records? Do you intend to mark existing records as archive and insert the new records? If one key-value-pair changes, do you want to replace/update all the key-value-pairs, or just the ones that changed? Etc, etc?

Comment: @Dems, I have 10 objects- each object has 5 fields. I only want to update the corresponding field in the Database if the corresponding field generated from the website-scraping has changed.

Comment: `Please give us the schema, and ideally some example (even if it's fictional) data.`

Comment: I don't get the problem. You already have an approach which sounds promising. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What aspect are you trying to achieve best in?

SQL calls, CPU usage, memory usage, bandwidth between CPU and SQL server, easiest to read, easiest to maintain, etc...

One memory improvement over your current approach would be to have the dbdict be `Dictionary<keytype, int>()` and only store the `GetHash()` values in it.

Or possibly store the `GetHash()` value in the database, so you can do similar to:

```
update table1 set col1 = "newvalueCol1", col2 = "newvalueCol2", colHash = @newHash
where id = @key1
   and colHash <> @newHash
```

Other than that I feel I'd need to know more about the situation to help more (what is too slow for you, example: code, schema, updates)

Answer (score 0):

Why process 10 rows if there is change on row 1.

```
Select count(*) from table1 where col1 <> "newVal1" or col2 <> "newVal2"  ...

Select count(*) from table2 where col1 <> "newVal1" or col2 <> "newVal2"  ...
```

In the question you state insert data but then in a comment you state update.

If update then simple

update table1 set col1 = "newvalueCol1" where col1 <> "newvalueCol1"

it would actually be more efficient to

```
update table1 set col1 = "newvalueCol1", col2 = "newvalueCol2" 
where col1 <> "newvalueCol1"
   or col2 <> "newvalueCol2"
```

Once you take a lock if only one has changed there is very little overhead to updating both.